# How to add space at the end of property value

Tags: java, resourcebundle

```
label.my.answer=My Answer
```

I would like to add spaces deliberately at the end of the above key (e.g. I would like to have 2 spaces at the end `"My Answer  "`)

Currently the java.util.ResourceBundle functionality kind of trims this piece of code while retrieving the value

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
label.myAnswer = My Answer\u0020\u0020
```

Note: identifiers with dots usually represent a hierarchy of names, and `my` is not a hierarchy level. You would certainly not define a Java class or a Java package of that name, would you?

Comment: But you wouldnt create a package named myAnswer either... As long as the name expresses well what its for who cares? Beside of that +1 for the answer

Comment: For example, the Eclipse Resource Bundle Editor cares. You can configure it that it regards dots as hierarchical separators, which are then displayed in a tree. You wouldn't want to have "my" as a node in that tree.

Comment: In this conext I have to say that you are right. Didnt know about this plugin so +1 for your comment for that. Unfortunately I dont find any download information about the derived Babel editor.

Comment: No problem. Many developers that I know just stick to the naming convention of "putting dots where I like" and don't think about the semantic implications.

Comment: That solution doesn't work in Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
label.myAnswer = My Answer\ \
```

Comment: this continues the property in the next line - not intended

Comment: No, it doesn't: look closer. The final backslash is not at the end of the line.

Comment: you are correct. Actually ResourceBundle should not trim the spaces, Property files are allowed to have trailing spaces. Which however I consider bad design and equally bad practice.

Comment: You don't need to pick on me just because you were wrong.